# C++ Collaboration

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, networking, collaboration

I'm trying to start a collaborative C++ project that requires multithreading, networking, MySQL and Unicode (UTF-16) support (essentially a networked application).

I've found the POCO library to be a source of all of these features and it seems like a good library to use.

This will be my first collaborative project so assume no knowledge of how to use GIT and alike. I have a server that I can use as a repository as I'd prefer to use my own than an online service.

What sort of setup would you suggest for this and how would you go about setting everything up?

Sorry if this seems like a specific 'Help me' request, but after trawling for days I assume this hasn't been discussed much and so any info you post here will help others who find themselves in my position.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: what do you mean by "collaborative project"? Is it just a way most of the teams work, i.e. a project developed by several developers, or anything more particular, like like open source with geographically distributed members etc.? Depending on that, I may share our experience that could be relevant

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I wonder where to start.

- Have you considered all possibilities for programming language, tools etc?
- Why do you say "requires multithreading" ? Multithreading is usually an optimisation, hence to require it initially is either an extremely premature optimisation, or a wise choice based on experience. However, you say this is "your first collaborative project", so presumably it's the former.
- Are any members of your team more experienced than you? If so, they should probably choose tools and technology (or at least have a hand in the decision).

Are you in a managerial position here? How experienced is your team?

If your team is very inexperienced, it might assume that this is a good idea. If it is experienced, they will probably want to a) Start in an easier language b) Do optimisations later rather than sooner.

I think it's fair to say that no software application "requires C++, multithreading, MySQL" as those are design decisions.

How well documented is your design? Has your team reviewed / critiqued it extensively?

How well documented are your requirements?

Comment: I'll try and answer in the same order you asked.

C++ has been chosen for speed and basic OOP. Java would be nice to use, but basic (maybe flawed) benchmarks on networking have shown it to be too slow. Any suggestions are welcome though.

Multithreading is a requirement in this project, it will not work without it. It is used in every aspect as a design element rather than an optimisation.

Assume I'm the most experienced, I'm making all the decisions and have probably had the most experience. The project is planned by me.

I'm looking for rather generic recommendations based upon features.

Answer (score 0):

http://gitref.org/ Will give you a good head start on learning git, which might just be the route you want to go if you're interested in a less centralized solution.

Comment: How would you go about setting up a collaborative environment with GIT that allows the use of libraries such as POCO by all collaborators? (Assume no knowledge please)